# Fragments or View Pager

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm new to android programming and I have a concept question. The app I'm trying to develop is pretty simple. It's basically an app that gathers information from a website and shows the info in a View Pager in different slides.

So far, what I've investigated is, I am to use an intent service to get the information from the remote website/db but the problem I'm having is trying to update the views inside the broadcast receiver.

I've been looking and I'm thinking maybe I'm going about it the wrong way. The requirements of the app are the following

- Be able to show multiple slides (same format/layout) with swipe action.
- Get information from website periodically (intent service with alarm manager I believe)

So what I'm looking for here is maybe some pointers on how to go about it. So far I've been trying to use View Pager to create the multiple slides and Intent Service to get the information. However, I'm having trouble to update the slide I'm looking for on the onReceive (I don't know how to reference it).

Here's some sample code that is related to my inquiry.

Main Activity and View Pager declarations

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Load main layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Show loading view while network loads content
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mLoadingView = findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner);

    // Initially hide the content view.
    mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Retrieve and cache the system's default "short" animation time.
    mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

    //Set clubs to display
    //TODO - Get this info from API
    //TODO - Remove HardCode
    ArrayList<Club> clubs = new ArrayList<Club>();
    //rep   -   REPUBLIKA MOVIL
    Club temp = new Club();
    temp.setId(0);
    temp.setClubCode("rep");
    temp.setHost("http://control.outech.com.mx");
    clubs.add(temp);
    /*
     * Creates a new Intent to start the ClubPullService
     * IntentService. Passes a URI in the
     * Intent's "data" field.
     */
    for(int i = 0; i < clubs.size(); i++){
        //Define intent service
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, ClubPullService.class);
        mServiceIntent.putExtra("club", clubs.get(i));

        // Starts the IntentService
        this.startService(mServiceIntent);          
    }

    /*
     * Setup receivers to get club information 
     */
    IntentFilter mStatusIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION);

    // Instantiates a new PullReceiver
    PullReceiver mPullReceiver = new PullReceiver();
    // Registers the PullReceiver and its intent filters
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mPullReceiver, mStatusIntentFilter);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPagerAdapter = new SlideAdapter();
    mPager = (ViewPager) mContentView;
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    //Creates the views in the pager
    for(int i = 0; i < clubs.size(); i++){
        RelativeLayout v0 = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate (R.layout.slide, null);
        mPagerAdapter.addView (v0);
        mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }       
}
```

Separate class broadcast receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Gets data from the incoming Intent    
    Club club = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.CLUB_INFORMATION);
    Log.v(LOG, "Received: "+club.getClubName());

    /*
    //Time of sync
    Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    today.setToNow();   
    TextView sync = (TextView) ctx.findViewById(R.id.textViewSyncValue);
    sync.setText(String.format(context.getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_sync), String.valueOf(today.format("%d/%m/%Y %k:%M:%S"))));        
    */

}
```

Comment: Why are you using a BroadcastReceiver if you're just pulling in information from a website?

Comment: I asked for suggestions as I'm maybe going about it the wrong way. If you have a different solution please post it as an answer.

Comment: Well, what you're doing would work, but you're going to need a reference to the ViewPager outside of the Activity/Receiver in order to link between the two (ie. overriding Application and setting/getting a reference to/from there). Although, if you're just making web requests that are directly linked to an Activity (as opposed to always running in the background outside the Activity), I would personally go with a combination of the default AsyncTask, HttpClient, and HttpGet classes (although I'm pretty sure there are some better libraries now-a-days)

Comment: How would I go about making this reference to the ViewPager, it is exactly what I'm having trouble with at the moment.

Comment: If you override Application, the variables you store in there will persist throughout the lifecycle of the app and not just a single Activity. So you would hold a reference in there and access it when needed.